# Whenever I add an 'AND' to my sql statement, the statement gives an error

Tags: php, mysql

It's my second time here... I might type this wrong but I hope not,
I am having a problem with php, whenever I put an AND statement in the sql query it gives me an error about the sql statement being incorrect. I want to do two SET statements for an mysqli update database query, but I cant seem to succeed.

I tried changing the variables up but it did not work.

```php
<?php session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION["admin"]) || $_SESSION["admin"] !== true){
    header("location: https://howcoolitis.net/home");
    exit;
}
require_once "config.php";



$banname = "";
$banmotive = "";
$deletename = "";
$deletemotive = "";
$ban_err = "";
$delete_err = "";
$unbanname = "";
$unban_err = "";
$adminname = "";
$admin_err = "";
$moderatorname = "";
$moderator_err = "";
$ban_success = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(isset($_POST['ban'])){
        $username = $_POST['ban'];
        $usernamesql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND Admin = '0'";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $usernamesql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) != 1){ 
                    $ban_err = "That user does not exist or is an admin!";
                }
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                if(empty($ban_err)){
                    // Prepare an update statement
                    $username = $_POST['ban'];
                    $banname = $_POST['ban'];
                    $banmotive = $_POST['ban-motive'];
                    $sql = "UPDATE users SET Banned = '1' and SET BannedMotive = ? and SET WHERE username = ?";

                    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
                        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_bannedmotive, $param_username);

                        $param_username = $username;
                        $param_bannedmotive = $banmotive;

                        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                            $ban_success = "You have successfully banned ".$username."!";
                        } else{
                            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                        }
                    }

                    // Close statement
                    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                }

                // Close connection
                mysqli_close($link);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $username = $_POST['delete'];
        $usernamesql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND Admin = '0'";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $usernamesql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) != 1){ 
                    $delete_err = "That user does not exist or is an admin!";
                }
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                if(empty($delete_err)){
                    // Prepare an update statement
                    $username = $_POST['delete'];
                    $deletename = $_POST['delete'];
                    $deletemotive = $_POST['delete-motive'];
                    $bansql = "UPDATE users SET Banned = '1' and SET DeletedMotive = ? WHERE username = ?";

                    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $bansql)){
                        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_deletedmotive, $param_username);

                        $param_username = $username;
                        $param_deletedmotive = $deletemotive;

                        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                            $bio_success = "You have successfully deleted ".$username."!";
                        } else{
                            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                        }
                    }

                    // Close statement
                    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                }

                // Close connection
                mysqli_close($link);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['unban'])){
        $username = $_POST['unban'];
        $usernamesql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND banned = '1'";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $usernamesql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) != 1){ 
                    $admin_err = "That user does not exist or has not been banned!";
                }
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                if(empty($admin_err)){
                    // Prepare an update statement
                    $username = $_POST['unban'];
                    $unbanname = $_POST['unban'];
                    $bansql = "UPDATE users SET Banned = '0' WHERE username = ?";

                    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $bansql)){
                        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

                        $param_username = $username;

                        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                            $bio_success = "You have successfully unbanned ".$username."!";
                        } else{
                            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                        }
                    }

                    // Close statement
                    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                }

                // Close connection
                mysqli_close($link);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['admin'])){
        $username = $_POST['admin'];
        $usernamesql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND Admin = '0' AND Moderator = '0'";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $usernamesql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) != 1){ 
                    $unban_err = "That user does not exist, is not a moderator or already is an admin";
                }
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                if(empty($unban_err)){
                    // Prepare an update statement
                    $username = $_POST['admin'];
                    $adminname = $_POST['admin'];
                    $bansql = "UPDATE users SET Admin = '1' WHERE username = ?";

                    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $bansql)){
                        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

                        $param_username = $username;

                        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                            $bio_success = "You have successfully admined ".$username."!";
                        } else{
                            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                        }
                    }

                    // Close statement
                    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                }

                // Close connection
                mysqli_close($link);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['moderator'])){
        $username = $_POST['moderator'];
        $usernamesql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND Moderator = '0'";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $usernamesql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) != 1){ 
                    $unban_err = "That user does not exist or is a moderator already!";
                }
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                if(empty($unban_err)){
                    // Prepare an update statement
                    $username = $_POST['admin'];
                    $adminname = $_POST['admin'];
                    $bansql = "UPDATE users SET Moderator = '1' WHERE username = ?";

                    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $bansql)){
                        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

                        $param_username = $username;

                        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                            $bio_success = "You have successfully made ".$username." a moderator!";
                        } else{
                            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                        }
                    }

                    // Close statement
                    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                }

                // Close connection
                mysqli_close($link);
            }
        }
    }
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HCII - Admin Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://howcoolitis.net/style.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 400px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body id = "particles-js">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Welcome to the admin panel, <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?> </h2>
            <form action="" method = "post">
                <label>Ban User</label>
                <input type="text"  name="ban" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $banname ?>" required><br>
                <label>Ban Motive</label>
                <input type="text" name="ban-motive" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $banmotive ?>" required><br>
                <?php echo $ban_err; ?><br><br> <?php echo $ban_success; ?>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Ban">
                </form>
                <br><br>
            <form action="" method = "post">
                <label>Delete User</label>
                <input type="text" name="delete" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $deletename ?>" required><br>
                <label>Delete Motive</label>
                <input type="text" name="delete-motive" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $deletemotive ?>" required><br>
                <?php echo $delete_err ?><br><br>
                <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete">
            </form>
                <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <a class="btn btn-link" href="https://howcoolitis.net/home"> Go Back To Main Page?</a><br><br>
            </div>
    </div>  
    <div class = "unban">
        <form action="" method = "post">
            <label>Unban User</label>
            <input type="text"  name="unban" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $unbanname ?>" required><br>
            <?php echo $unban_err; ?><br>
            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Unban">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class = "role">
        <form action="" method = "post">
            <label>Admin A User</label>
            <input type="text"  name="admin" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $adminname ?>" required><br>
            <?php echo $admin_err; ?><br>
            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Admin"><br>
        </form>
        <br><br>
        <form action = "" method = "post">
            <label>Make A Userr A Moderator</label>
            <input type="text"  name="moderator" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $moderatorname ?>" required><br>
            <?php echo $moderator_err; ?><br>
            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Moderator">
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src = "https://howcoolitis.net/script.js"></script>
        <script src = "https://howcoolitis.net/app.js"></script>
        <style> 
        body {  
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0; 
        }
        .unban{
        background-color: #fff; 
        position: absolute;   
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-top: 18%;
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 1em;     
        width: 20%;  
        height: 16%;         
        border-radius: 0; 
        border-radius: 8px;
        }
        .role{
        background-color: #fff; 
        position: absolute;   
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-top: 28%;
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 1em;     
        width: 20%;  
        height: 25%;         
        border-radius: 0; 
        border-radius: 8px;
        }
        .wrapper 
        {
        background-color: #fff; 
        position: absolute;   
        margin-left: 40%;
        margin-top: 16.45%;
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 1em;     
        width: 20%;  
        height: 47%;         
        border-radius: 0; 
        border-radius: 8px;
        } </style>  
</body>
</html>
```

I thought it would just update both with the set parameters but it wont

Please help me with this.

Comment: Basically I need help with an error on how to put 2 set statements in one query. If anyone can explain how to do that.

Comment: No need to provide all your code, just the code with the issue in your question. No way for us to know which query there is failing.

Comment: Your question is related to basic MySQL update syntax.   The code is rather good in general but the problem is the *guesswork*.  Do not put arbitrary statements (AND or anything else) 8n your query. Instead, refer to MySQL manual or any tutorial for the proper syntax.

Comment: All we need is the one query that fails and the error message. Not pages and pages of unrelated code to sift through.

Comment: When updating, use a `,` instead of `AND`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use comma `,` instead of `AND` in your query Like this:

```
 $bansql = "UPDATE users SET Banned = '1' , DeletedMotive = ? WHERE username = ?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET Banned = '1' and SET BannedMotive = ? and SET WHERE username = ?";
```

your query should be:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET Banned = '1',BannedMotive = ? WHERE username = ?";
```